# Recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i'd like to know what i'm doing wrong over here. I'm building a CRUD app in Kotlin, and i'm using the recyclerview to make the readData page. The problem is, when i'm on the readData page doesn't show me anything, just the text views, so i debugged and when i join in the page, show this message: *"Recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout"*.

Here's my code:
(i'm brazilian, so, some words are in portuguese, but you'll get it.)

**verDados.kt**

```
package com.nicolas.csrd

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_ver_database.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class verDados : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_database)

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        reference = database.getReference("usuarios")

        verDados()

        btn_voltar.setOnClickListener() {
            startActivity(Intent(this@verDados, Dashboard::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun verDados() {
        reference.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("cancelar", p0.toString())
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                //Colocando os usuarios numa lista
                var list = ArrayList<DatabaseModelo>()

                for (data in p0.children) {
                    val model = data.getValue(DatabaseModelo::class.java)
                    list.add(model as DatabaseModelo)
                }
                if (list.size > 0) {
                    val ususariosModelo = usuariosModelo(list)
                    recyclerview.adapter = ususariosModelo
                }

            }
        })
    }
}
```

**DatabaseModel**

```
package com.nicolas.csrd

class DatabaseModelo() {
    lateinit var email: String
    lateinit var senha: String

    constructor(email: String, senha: String) : this() {
        this.email = email
        this.senha = senha
    }
}
```

**usuariosModelo.kt (recyclerview adapter)**

```
package com.nicolas.csrd

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.usuarios_modelo.view.*


class usuariosModelo(val list: ArrayList<DatabaseModelo>): RecyclerView.Adapter<usuariosModelo.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val email = itemView.campo_email
        val senha = itemView.campo_senha
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.usuarios_modelo, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.email.text = list[position].email
        holder.senha.text = list[position].senha
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
}
```

----- XML FILES -----

**activity_ver_database.xml (read data page)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_voltar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DADOS"
            android:textColor="#7ec1d1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:letterSpacing="0.15"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Todos os usuários cadastrados"
            android:textColor="#7ec1d1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"

            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_thin"
            />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_cadastrar"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#7ec1d1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:text="Deseja cadastrar alguém? Clique aqui."
            android:textColor="@color/white2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have no defined an adaptor for the `RecyclerView` that you are using. Somewhere inn your `onCreate` method, create the adaptor and set it to the `RecyclerView`. Something like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_database)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.apply {
            adapter = usuariosModelo(listOfItems)
        }

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        reference = database.getReference("usuarios")

        verDados()

        btn_voltar.setOnClickListener() {
            startActivity(Intent(this@verDados, Dashboard::class.java))
            finish()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can i just copy and paste this code on verDados.kt ? Or do i need to convert that in Kotlin or smth like this? I'm really noob on this hahaha

Comment: You should be able to. The only thing you might also need to add is:
```private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView``` where you have your lateinit variables

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem just adding the tag below inside the recyclerview tag in the .xml file:

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

I hope that help y'all!